# How do I put a SuperView on top of a SubView?

Tags: iphone, subview, superview

I want to put a SuperView (with a transparent background) on top of my SubView. Is there a way of doing that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why would you want such a strange views hierarchy anyway? Just add an additional sub-view on top of all others.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove your "SubView" from your parent view.
2. Add your "SuperView" as a subview of your parent view.
3. Add your "SubView" as a subview of "SuperView".

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear - the SuperView is actually the parent.

Comment: If that's the case, your SubView already has a SuperView: the parent view.

Comment: But I would like to bring that parent in front of the SubView. How would I do that? Sorry for being so confusing, it's been a late night..

Comment: You can't. By definition the parent will always be the parent of the subview. You make a subview of the parent ("ParentSubView") and either rearrange the order of subviews of the parent or make the "SubView" a subview of "ParentSubView".